# jQuery Read More/Read Less based on child <p> within a <div> using show(); hide(); and size();

Tags: jquery, html, show-hide

I have created a script using jQuery that shows and hides all but the first paragraph within a div to give a Read More/Read Less effect. The basic functions of it are this:

- Initially hide all but first p within the .description div
- Show a "read more" button if there is more than 1 p within the div
- Show all the paragraphs when read more in clicked, also replace the
  read more button with a read less button
- Hide all but first paragraph and replace read less with read more
  when "Read less" is clicked

You can view this script here: http://jsfiddle.net/0li4tw/Nv27E/

```
paragraphCount = $(".description > p").size();

$("#hider").hide();
$("#shower").hide();

if (paragraphCount > 1) {
    $("#shower").show();
}

$( "#hider" ).click(function() {
    $(".description p").not(":first").hide();
    $("#hider").hide();
    $("#shower").show();
});

$( "#shower" ).click(function() {
    $(".description p").show();
    $("#shower").hide();
    $("#hider").show();
});

$(".description p").not(":first").hide();
```

Is there any obvious issues with the script - particular browser related (I am quite new to jquery/javascript), or perhaps are there any more efficient methods of obtaining the same results?

Many thanks

Comment: If it works and your after a code review you'd be better off posting on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, is there any way to remove the post from here as not to dupe?

Comment: No, not yet at least. Don't worry about it. It's not doing any harm.

Comment: If you're interested [this is in the pipeline](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191347/can-we-add-code-review-to-the-migration-list) once codereview comes out of beta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use something to target all descriptions, and wrap all the toggle-able content in a container, in case i wanted to do something else than just toggle/hide them (maybe effects?).

```
$('.description').each(function() {

   // if there are more than just one P    
   if (  $(this).children('p').length > 1 ) {
      // wrap them in a container & also have class .hidden (hides content)
      $('p:not(:first-child)').wrapAll('<div class="descr-extended hidden"></div>');
   }

});


$('.descr-toggler').on('click', function() {
    $('.descr-extended').toggleClass('hidden');  // toggling visibility w .hidden
});
```

More -> http://jsfiddle.net/0li4tw/Nv27E/

Improvement: Use some relativity w the buttons "prev('.desc-extended')" (and add buttons from script only if you've hidden content)

Comment: Thanks, that is probably a more elegant solution. How would I change the text of the button depending on the show/hide state? http://jsfiddle.net/0li4tw/Nv27E/3/

Comment: Depends on what language you are going to present it with, maybe have a invisible field that store the text to be displayed on the button. Maybe add the text with data-info and use that as text on the buttons :)

Answer (score 0):

It works. You could have used toggle() to hide when shown, and show when hidden. It reduces your code a bit:

```
paragraphCount = $(".description > p").size();

$("#hider").hide();
$("#shower").hide();

if (paragraphCount > 1) {
    $("#shower").show();
}

$( "#hider, #shower" ).click(function() {
    $(".description p").not(":first").toggle();
    $("#hider").toggle();
    $("#shower").toggle();
});

$(".description p").not(":first").hide();
```

Answer (score -1):

I have done a similar experiment. This supports complex HTML Tags too inside the more. And the best part is, it uses `data-` attributes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    length = 200;
    cHtml = $(".content").html();
    cText = $(".content").text().substr(0, length).trim();
    $(".content").addClass("compressed").html(cText + "... <a href='#' class='exp'>More</a>");
    window.handler = function()
    {
        $('.exp').click(function(){
            if ($(".content").hasClass("compressed"))
            {
                $(".content").html(cHtml + "<a href='#' class='exp'>Less</a>");
                $(".content").removeClass("compressed");
                handler();
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                $(".content").html(cText + "... <a href='#' class='exp'>More</a>");
                $(".content").addClass("compressed");
                handler();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    handler();
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/SZLgs/